# PHP-SQl Autocomplete search

Tags: php, sql, search

I've writing a code to log in a user and display his various details. This is working perfectly fine. On addition to it; I added a autocomplete search that doesn't seem to work. I'm using Jquery's autocomplete. The fields in the search box are searched from SQL.

But nothing happens. I type in the text in the text-field but nothing happens.

Here's my whole corrected PHP code (excluding the connection file)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: keywordList,
    minLength: 1,

  });
});
</script>

<?php echo keywordArray(); ?>
<?php function keywordArray()
{
  $rsKeywords = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job");

  $output = '<script>'."\n";
  $output .= 'var keywordList = [';

  while($row_rsKeywords = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsKeywords))
  {
    $output .= '"'.$row_rsKeywords['work'].'",';
  }

  $output = substr($output,0,-1); //Get rid of the trailing comma
  $output .= '];'."\n";
  $output .= '</script>';
  return $output;
}
?>
```

//search script:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
                        echo "Your search was invalid";
                        exit;
                    } 

                    $keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keywords']);
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM job WHERE work='$keyword' or work LIKE 'ANOTHER_PARAMETER' LIMIT 5";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

                    echo //details etc
>?
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't answered my question either.

Comment: Try to write your question in an appropriate way. Try to explain what happens, for example.

Comment: Oh that. Nothing happens. No error. I write something in the text-field. And nothing happens. Wait I'll just edit my question.

Comment: Use a javascript debugger, like firebug, or the built-in debugger in Google Chrome

Comment: Ya .I used Fire-bug. Don't know what the problem is. That's why posted here in SO.

Comment: Well it's a little bit hard to debug if we don't even know what the error is. Did you look at the generated HTML source code? Does it look correct?

Comment: neither us know without some debug information. for example where the js explodes, or if the petition its being made at all. making a shorter version of the code may help too

Comment: Okay I'll edit the question after doing some more research. Thanks.

Comment: dont take this bad. if you improve your question, it'll be more likely to get an answer

Comment: Seems like the error is in PHP. I ran a test here only with the `SELECT` part in PHP using only `SELECT * FROM TABLE` and your jQuery codes with UI Autocomplete and it works fine here.

Comment: I resolved it. I didn't define `"ui.item.value"`
Here's the corrected code:
`<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: keywordList,
    minLength: 1,
     
  });
});
</script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my whole corrected PHP code (excluding the connection file)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: keywordList,
    minLength: 1,

  });
});
</script>

<?php echo keywordArray(); ?>
<?php function keywordArray()
{
  $rsKeywords = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job");

  $output = '<script>'."\n";
  $output .= 'var keywordList = [';

  while($row_rsKeywords = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsKeywords))
  {
    $output .= '"'.$row_rsKeywords['work'].'",';
  }

  $output = substr($output,0,-1); //Get rid of the trailing comma
  $output .= '];'."\n";
  $output .= '</script>';
  return $output;
}
?>
```

//search script:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
                        echo "Your search was invalid";
                        exit;
                    } 

                    $keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keywords']);
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM job WHERE work='$keyword' or work LIKE 'ANOTHER_PARAMETER' LIMIT 5";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

                    echo //details etc
>?
```